Problem with understanding advantage of QAOA over bruteforce
I am trying to figure out with QAOA alghorithm. I use the example from this qiskit notebook https://github.com/Qiskit/textbook/blob/main/notebooks/ch-applications/qaoa.ipynb.
I have the question to this code. In the function compute_expectation function maxcut_obj is called for every possible bit string of solution from 0 to 2^n, and expectation value is calculated based on this process. The goal of the algorithm is to find the optimal parametres of the curcuit which minimize the expectation value. But if we do this with such way, we calculate the cost function for every bit string and we do it every iteration of the optimizer. Won't the much easier way be finding maximum value of the cost function for every bit sring, if we already calculate it during the calculation of the expectation value? And the maximum value of the cost function will be the solution of the problem! And in this case bruteforce is simpler and faster then QAOA!
def maxcut_obj(solution, graph):
    """Given a bit string as a solution, this function returns
    the number of edges shared between the two partitions
    of the graph.
    Args:
        solution: (str) solution bit string
        graph: networkx graph
    Returns:
        obj: (float) Objective
    """
    # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    obj = 0
    for i, j in graph.edges():
        if solution[i] != solution[j]:
            obj -= 1
    return obj

def compute_expectation(counts, graph):
        """Computes expectation value based on measurement results
        Args:
            counts: (dict) key as bit string, val as count
            graph: networkx graph
        Returns:
            avg: float
                 expectation value
        """
        avg = 0
        sum_count = 0
        for bit_string, count in counts.items():
            obj = maxcut_obj(bit_string, graph)
            avg += obj * count
            sum_count += count
        return avg/sum_count

The latex render on github isn't working correctly with this notebook, this is normal version in colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14hGZFGEU6BpGXGkU5vU-rCFoBfjHto9R?usp=sharing

You are not iterating over all bit strings, only the ones that have appeared as outcomes to measuring the circuits. The number of bit strings you iterate over is therefore bounded above by the number of shots you do so shouldn't scale exponentially.
In practise a different approach is suggested. The expectations of the Pauli strings in the Hamiltonian are measured and these are used to build up the approximation for the expectation of the whole Hamiltonian. Terms in the Hamiltonian that commute are jointly measured and this speeds up the process even more!

thanks for the explanation! have you any examples or notebooks with the realization of the practise variant QAOA? I have found only this example https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qaoa_maxcut/
